# Shared google sheet with script button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shared

I have shared Google sheet in which there is button with function Clear filled rows and Send ( sending the data to other sheet) But when an user enter in the table the button is not active. They can click on it but the script is not working its giving standard options ( cut,copy,delete)
How i can make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add more details i.e. are the users editors or viewers?

Comment: Hi, all users are editors